# Write data in specific position

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following code:

```cs
class Dto
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string DataN { get; set; }
    public string DataN1 { get; set; }
}

class DtoMap : ClassMap<Dto>
{
    public DtoMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Data1).Index(0);

        // Note that I need to skip N columns
        Map(x => x.DataN).Index(N);
        Map(x => x.DataN1).Index(N1);
    }
}

// create csv

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, csvConfiguration))
{
    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
    streamWriter.Flush();

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Expected result is the following CSV table:

| header 1 | header ... | header n | header n + 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | ... | Data N | Data N + 1 |
| Data 2 | ... | Data N | Data N + 1 |

Seems that indexes are ignored during writing csv file. Problem occurred in 15.0.6 and 26.0.0 versions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CsvHelper will output columns in the order specified by the indices, but it will not add empty columns for missing indices.  If you need to do that, you can use `Map().Index(i).Constant("");` to indicate a constant value should be used at a specific index `i`.  Use that to fill in a constant empty value for the columns you want to leave empty:

```
class DtoMap : ClassMap<Dto>
{
    const int N = 12;

    public DtoMap() : this(true) { }
    
    public DtoMap(bool includeEmptyColumns)
    {
        Map(x => x.Data1).Index(0);

        if (includeEmptyColumns)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
            {
                Map().Index(i).Constant("");
            }
        }

        // Note that I need to skip N columns
        Map(x => x.DataN).Index(N);
        Map(x => x.DataN1).Index(N + 1);
    }
}
```

See: *[Constant Value](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/constant-value)*.

This leaves the column titles empty.  If you need to provide some default column title you can specify one with `.Name(string)`:

```
Map().Index(i).Constant("").Name($"Column {i}");
```

You will not be able to use this class map to **read** your CSV, however, because (as of CsvHelper 26.1.0 at least) the reader will throw an error when a column is not mapped to a class member *even if it is constant*.  To work around the error, use `new DtoMap(false)` when reading, i.e.:

```
var newRecords = ReadCSV(csv, new DtoMap(false), config);

static List<TRecords> ReadCSV<TRecords>(byte [] data, ClassMap<TRecords> map, CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamWriter, csvConfiguration))
    {
        csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap(map);
        return csvReader.GetRecords<TRecords>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WHGSVL) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nzqzMQ).

Comment: You save my day. This is nice and clever solution.